# Phonegap /Cordova Whietlist Logic

Tags: cordova

The Cordova documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md) explains the purpose of the Navigation and Intent whitelists quite clearly.  What is less clear to me is just why they are necessary. The clickable links that appear in the webview owned by a hybrid app one creates are well "owned" by that app so it knows all about them in the first place right?  So then it would not go and provide links that should not be clicked by its user.

Clearly, there is a flaw in my reasoning there somewhere or else these whitelist spec options would not be there.  I would be much obliged to anyone who might be explain the "intent" behind these whitelists.

Comment: from time to time, security issues appear and "hackers" manage to insert and execute code into your app, so the whitelist add some extra security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jcesarmobile says in his comment, depending upon your app of course, hackers can trick your app or user into inserting something into the app that can link to sources on the web that could have malicious code in them.  Since they know you are running in a Cordova environment, they have access not only to standard web javascript controls, but any plugins you may be running and could perform any action that you can perform (make a phone call, request users contacts, etc).  If your app shows any kind of input that is being procured from the outside world that you are not directly in control of, and you miss any sanitization before outputing it you are vulnerable to XSS injection, the whitelist reduces the damage that can be done with said XSS injection (i.e. they couldn't load scripts from another machine).